# Python cutting string results in error

Tags: python, substring

I am trying to cut my string from `"<em class=\"txt\">"` to `</em">`.

```
type = line[line.find("<em class=\"txt\">")+16:line.find(line.find("</em>"),line.find("<em class=\"txt\">"))]
```

And this is error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I sure there's something wrong with adding int in this code. But why it want to convert int to str? I want to add int to result of line.find() so also to int. It should work properly.

Generally I want to achieve this:

**Input**:

```
<em class="txt">blablabla</em>
```

**Output**:

```
blablabla
```

Comment: Perhaps you should be using an XML/HTML parser...

Comment: @MattDMo It's not necessary in this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first argument to the `line.find` after the `:` is the result of calling `line.find()`, which yields the `int` that the error is complaining about.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you. That was pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Beautiful Soup parser.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '<em class="txt">blablabla</em>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.select('em.txt')[0].text
'blablabla'
```